# Java Remote debugging issue in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I have such problem: I started debug in "Remote debugging Application" and it started without errors. Also I've added breakpoints in correct places. But when I'm running my application there is no stop on breakpoints. I was suggested that the root cause can be in threads. [image]

Maybe someone has had such situtation?

Comment: Your source code in Eclipse differs from the actual code being executed remotely

Comment: Check if the icon of your breakpoint has a small checked icon overlay, if not the code does not match the code you are executing on your remote machine.

Comment: @SWoeste All breakpoints have checked icon

Comment: @FranMontero Did you see it from threads? Or its just your guess?

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk Then you have at least no problem with your source. The "Skip All Breakpoints" Button is off, right?

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk I guess it based on my xperience ;)

Comment: @SWoeste yes, right, it's off